# Search and pagination in media popup don't work properly

Tags: media, search, 9, paging

In the /admin/content/media page, I have more than one button for the pagination.

> [image: screenshot]

The search is working properly.

> [image: screenshot]

When I edit a media on some node, in the popup, I only have one button in the pagination.

> [image: screenshot]

The search isn't always working.
Here, I'm making the search from the page 2, where the image isn't available directly.

> [image: screenshot]

It only works when the searched image is on the current page (selected by the pagination).

Here, I'm making the search from the page 1, where the image is available directly.

> [image: screenshot]

Is this the default behavior for the popup? My client doesn't like it; he'd like to have the "working" behavior.

Do I have some configuration to do?

I'm using the latest version of Drupal 9 (9.2.7) and the latest version of Gin for the admin theme.

I looked in another project of mine, with the same behavior, but it seems that the search only works on page 1 of the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the pagination, I had to change the pagination from *mini* to *complete* here to have more than one pagination.

> /admin/structure/views/view/media_library/edit/